# Finding the oldest most recent visit. (Minimum grouped by maximum)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the oldest date in a list, but I only want to consider the most recent entry for each possible "person".

I.e. consider the following dataset (dates are varchar 103 i.e. dd/mm/yyyy)

```
+--------+------+------------+
| Person | Shop | Date       |
+--------+------+------------+
| A      | X    | 09/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| A      | X    | 12/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| A      | Y    | 12/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| B      | X    | 01/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| B      | X    | 13/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| B      | Y    | 11/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| C      | X    | 14/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| C      | Y    | 18/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
| C      | Y    | 07/01/2017 |
+--------+------+------------+
```

If I wanted to find the minimum date usage for each of the "Shops" (i.e. MIN(DATE) GROUP BY Shop), then I would get 01/01/2017 for shop X and 07/01/2017 for Y. However, in both of these visits the person who visited has come to the shop at a later date, so I don't want to consider these dates as part of the "oldest most recent" visit.

To be clear, I would like to know out of each customer's most recent visit, which of those is the oldest. i.e. when was the last date that someone visited the shop but has not since returned.

Do I need to go via a temporary table where I extract the MAX(Date) group by Shop, or is there a way of getting the dates 12/01/2017 for X and 11/01/2017 for Y straight from this dataset?

I would like the following results

```
+------+------------+
| Shop | Date       |
+------+------------+
| X    | 12/01/2017 |
+------+------------+
| Y    | 11/01/2017 |
+------+------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add the expected result set for clarification, please.

Comment: so you want the oldest visit but only from those persons who visited only once ?

Comment: You really should start storing dates in the date datatype. That is what it is designed for. I continue to be shocked at how many people think this is ok. Those same people would never store integers in a varchar column.

Comment: Added Olivier, and GuidoG: I would like to know what is the oldest visit (over all customers) that constitutes a customer's most recent visit to the shop.

Comment: Sean, it is stored as a datetime - this is just for simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try a select inside a select:

```
CREATE TABLE #VISIT (Person CHAR(1), Shop CHAR(1), [Date] DATE)

INSERT INTO  #VISIT
SELECT 'A','X','09/01/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','X','01/12/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','Y','01/12/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','X','01/01/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','X','01/13/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Y','01/11/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','X','01/14/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','Y','01/18/2017'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','Y','01/07/2017'

SELECT minDate.Shop
    ,Min(minDate.lastVisit)
FROM (
    SELECT Person
        ,Shop
        ,Max([Date]) lastVisit
    FROM #VISIT
    GROUP BY Person
        ,Shop
    ) AS minDate
GROUP BY minDate.Shop
```

Comment: You were 3 minutes earlier!

Answer (score 4):

The  easiest approach is using the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
with cte as
(
   select Person, Shop, [Date],
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person Order By CONVERT(datetime, t.[Date], 103) DESC)
   fromk dbo.TableName t
)
select Person, Shop, [Date]
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Why don't you store dates as `date`/`datetime` but as `varchar`?

Comment: I don't think this query returns the expected result. The OP wants to get the latest-per-Person-per-Shop date. And then get the earliest-per-Shop value.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: Maybe i haven't read the question carefully enough. But he stated that he "only wants the most recent entry for each possible 'person'". However, he can modify it easily: `PARTITION BY Person, Shop...`